# Error: "DENSITY_XHIGH cannot be resolved or is not a field"

Tags: android, eclipse

I know I must miss something fundamental, but I cannot figure it out after scratching my head for a while.

I am using DisplayMetrics.DENSITY_XHIGH in a switch block, If the cursor is on DisplayMetricsm, Eclipse's intellisense shows the following available constants:

```
int DENSITY_DEFAULT The reference density used throughout the system. 
int DENSITY_HIGH Standard quantized DPI for high-density screens. 
int DENSITY_LOW Standard quantized DPI for low-density screens. 
int DENSITY_MEDIUM Standard quantized DPI for medium-density screens. 
int DENSITY_TV Standard quantized DPI for 720p TV screens. 
int DENSITY_XHIGH Standard quantized DPI for extra-high-density screens.
```

Please note DENSITY_XHIGH is among the constants.  However, Eclipse refuses to accept it, and gives the error "DENSITY_XHIGH cannot be resolved or is not a field".

If the cursor is on DENSITY_XHIGH, the intellisense gives 4 quick fixes using the following constants:

```
DENSITY_DEFAULT 
DENSITY_HIGH 
DENSITY_LOW  
DENSITY_MEDIUM
```

Any tip will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have just figured out: I needed to change the Project Build Target to higher version.  I have changed it from Android 2.2 to Android 4.0.3. Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not the right thing to do if your application supports devices below API leve 4.0.
Use the integer values instead.MDPI=160,DEFAULT=160,DENSITY_HIGH=240,DENSITY_MEDIUM=160,DENSITY_TV=213,DENSITY_XHIGH=320

Comment: Are those symbols treated as their corresponding integers by the compiler?

Comment: definitly. You can replace each qualifier with corresponding integer values